# Fuji AV-150 camera doesn't work with Ubuntu 14.04 as it did with 13.10

Tags: mount, 14.04, camera, mtp, mass-storage

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit). I could access the 4GB memory of my fujifilm AV-150 digital camera through nautilus in 13.10, but it is no longer shown in 14.04!

#### `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 04cb:021b Fuji Photo Film Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

#### `lsblk`

```
prasad@Trusty-ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  99.9G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  30.2G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   100G  0 part /mnt/Linux
├─sda6   8:6    0   200G  0 part /mnt/Media
├─sda7   8:7    0   300G  0 part 
└─sda8   8:8    0 201.3G  0 part /media/prasad/Home
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   300M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   128M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0  39.5G  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   250G  0 part 
├─sdb6   8:22   0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sdb7   8:23   0    10G  0 part 
├─sdb8   8:24   0    28G  0 part 
└─sdb9   8:25   0  28.6G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  32.8M  0 rom
```

[dmesg](http://pastebin.com/J841Re1B)

The camera is detected but not mounted as a mass storage. In ubuntu 13.10, it detects and mounts automatically without any hassle.

Comment: Add `dmesg` output

Comment: @Naveen added :)

Comment: Try downgrading to the last stable kernel release in 13.10  The same thing happened to my Network Card in my laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1296275)

The camera will be detected after executing following commands

**Option One**

```
echo 'ACTION="add", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:060101:*", ENV{ID_GPHOTO2}="1", ENV{GPHOTO2_DRIVER}="PTP", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"' | sudo tee /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-6.rules
```

Then unplug/replug the camera.

**Option Two**

```
sudo -H gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2-6.rules
```

and make the file look like this:

```
ACTION!="add", GOTO="libgphoto2_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="libgphoto2_usb_end"
ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"
ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:060101:*", ENV{ID_GPHOTO2}="1", ENV{GPHOTO2_DRIVER}="PTP", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"

LABEL="libgphoto2_rules_end"
```

thanks to [Martin pitt](https://launchpad.net/%7Epitti)

Answer (score 0):

I have virtually the same problem but with another camera brand. To get access to the pictures while the basic problem is not solved I use a workaround which is described in my posting:

[Canon IXUS 155 camera no longer found when connected to USB after update to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454651/canon-ixus-155-camera-no-longer-found-when-connected-to-usb-after-update-to-14-0)