# Canon IXUS 155 camera no longer found when connected to USB after update to 14.04

Tags: usb, mount, 14.04, camera

Previously I used Ubuntu 13 or older versions on my PCs and the Canon IXUS 155 Camera was detected on their USB ports. With Ubuntu 14.04 this is suddenly no longer true.

BTW: My other camera, a Nikon, is still detected easily when I use the same cable. Likewise USB sticks and other USB devices show up when plugged in.

On another PC which I have also updated to UBUNTU 14.04 the same problem occurred.

When I connected the IXUS 155 to another computer with Windows OS there it works. It may not be a problem of the camera I think.

When I started 'lsub' in the terminal and the cam connected I found a Canon device listed.

****-desktop:~$ lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0461:4de3 Primax Electronics, Ltd
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 001 Device 015: ID 04a9:328a Canon, Inc.

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0603:00f2 Novatek Microelectronics Corp.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

Best regards

Johannes

Edit: After some trial and error I was able to connect to my camera now and download the pictures using the 'gphoto2' command line interface. (This is just a workaround and not what I really want)

Comment: Thank you for gphoto2 command line hint; I download files from camera easily with command: gphoto2 --get-all-files . But first I had to kill gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor process.

Comment: See also this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1296275

Answer (score 2):

I could not access my Nikon Coolpix camera after installing Ubuntu 14.04.
I opened the Ubuntu Software Center, and downloaded "Camera (camera.app)".
It found my camera and downloaded my photos.

Comment: camera.app worked also for me, but the interface is ugly...